# How to update timeStamp field in a firestore document from cloud function?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I use the following code to update the `timeStamp` field in a firestore document from a cloud function:

```
  exports.updateDateWhenPhotoAdded = functions.firestore
  .document('posts/{postId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) =>
  {
      const userId = snap.data().userId;

      return db.collection('following').doc(`${userId}`).update({ latestPostTimeStamp: `${snap.data().timeStamp.toDate()}` });

  });
```

`timeStamp` field has the datatype `timestamp`. But, after executing the above code, **the field is automatically converted to string datatype** and timeStamp updated is not in the default timestamp format('MMMM dd,yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss a z'). How to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field is showing up as a string in the database because you're passing a string.  That's what the backtick quotes do in JavaScript - build a string.

If you want to copy a timestamp from one document to another, simply pass the raw field value without converting it to a string.

```
return db.collection('following').doc(userId).update({
    latestPostTimeStamp: snap.data().timeStamp
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Comment: how to do that? is there anyway to pass `snap.data().timeStamp` to that function?

Comment: I think you don't need to pass this, that already generate a server timestamp object to your firestoreDB , you can find more information here :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue